# React TypeScript 4.9.5 => onChange typesafe error in React Bootstrap FormControl

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, react-typescript, form-control

I'm getting the error `"Type '(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement | HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<FormControlElement>'."` in the following code on the `onChange()` attribute in `"Form.Control"` tag.

It is a simple code to update useState hook on change event. I have two elements, an `input(FormControl)` and a `Select(FormSelect)`. It works as intended  when I create an individual `onChange()` method for both of them but when I use `Union( | )` for `"HTMLSelectElement"` and `"HTMLInputElement"` in a single method as shown below it throws the error.

```
const handleChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement | HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setUsers({ ...users, [name]: value });
    console.log(users);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group className='mb-3' controlId='formBasicName'>
          <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={users?.name}
            name='name'
            id='name'
            type='text'
            placeholder='Name'
          />
       </Form.Group>
       <Form.Group className='mb-3' controlId='formBasicRole'>
          <Form.Select
            aria-label='Select Role'
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={users?.role}
            name='role'
          >
            <option>Select</option>
            <option value='Admin'>Admin</option>
            <option value='User'>User</option>
          </Form.Select>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now if I remove the `"HTMLSelectElement |"` from the parameter, the `onChange()` in `"Form.Control"` tag will start working fine but as expected, the one in `"Form.Select"` will throw an error. I also tried  changing the `"Form.Control"` to simple `"input"` tag and also creating separate methods after which it works just fine but I still wonder why it doesn't work when I use a `Union( | )`.